# Using find and zipgrep to find a string in zipfiles in subfodlers

Tags: grep, cygwin

after much trial and error, I've finally got a cygwin command that will print all the lines containing a given string in zipped logfiles

```
find -name "*.zip" | xargs -l zipgrep "QUICTest" -n > quic.test
```

It tells me the name of the file within the zip file, I'm also getting the line number - but what I can't figure out, is how to also print the zipfile
I figure I have to wrap this in a separate logger, but I still can't see a way to extract the zip filename and path

I'm happy that I'm getting the correct results, but just not that I can't actually be sure of where we find the files - as they're all generic logfiles, they'll be titled with a date and time, but no other useful information.
Many thanks

Update - I have a partial answer - I have edited the zipgrep script to change the sed replace operation after egrep to poke in the zipfile name

```
 status_grep=` ( \
 ( unzip -p-L "$zipfile" "$i" | \
 egrep $opt "$pat" 1>&4 ; echo $? >&3 ) 4>&1 | \
 sed "s|^|${zipfile}::${i}:|" 1>&4 \
 ) 3>&1 `
fi
```

I've just realised that it bombs out processing subfolders with spaces in them, so I will continue working on that.
Has anyone else solved this problem before?  I suspect I'm still missing an easier option

Comment: did you tried adding `-H` option to `zipgrep`?

Comment: Hi Ymonad, it just tells me that it's standard input - but I've just been looking in the script and think I might have just worked it out.  Might take a bit of fiddling ;)

Answer (score 1):

solved... I'm a plonker sometimes
It looks like with cygwin I need to use

```
find -name "*.zip" -print0 | xargs -0 -l zipgrep "QUICTest" -n | tee quic.test
```

I didn't realise that I needed to use a combination of -print0 for find as well as -0 and -l for xargs, as you need both sets of directives.